# MUI toggleButton returns null instead of It's value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to add a text and an Icon to the ToggleButton,like this

> <ToggleButton sx={{ color: '#000' }} data-testid='MainForm-media_type-ToggleButtonStyled-image' value={CONSTANTS.IMG_VALUE}>
>
> {t('TEMPLATE.IMAGE')}

But what happens is : when I click on the text or the Icon, It returns null instead of the value of the button, and when I click on any place in the button but It's not the icon or the text (the white area), the bttuon works and it return the value I assigned

[image]

How can I solve this?